# Unable to disable rows in WPF DataGrid using Style trigger

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to disable rows based on a property "IsEditable".

This is my `RowStyle`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable}" Value="False">
             <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I'm able to disable the entire grid using the same property but I'm unable to disable rows.

"IsEditable" property is defined in my ViewModel. My datacontext is also the ViewModel.

This is my grid code

```
 <DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="0" MouseDoubleClick="listViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"  
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
                      BorderBrush="#FF898C95" ItemsSource="{Binding EqpGrpList}" CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFDEDBDB"
                      VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFDEDBDB" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      Margin="0,-5,0,0" Background="White" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}">

              <DataGrid.Columns...>

  </DataGrid>
```

I have included the row style in `UserControl.Resources`.

Comment: Your Xaml works perfectly fine. You should provide more code here so we can see where the problem occurs.

Comment: Where is the IsEditable property defined? In a viewmodel at a datagrid's level or at a row's level?

Comment: I have edited my question. The IsEditable property is defined at the ViewModel level which is my datacontext.

Comment: Then the IsEditable property does not exist at the objects in EqpGrpList? If so, I think that is your problem. Maybe if you set ElementName or RelativeSource in the binding to the DataGrid? <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Value="False">

Comment: @nan Have you had any progress?

Comment: @Björn I'm sorry I could not update earlier since I was occupied. Unfortunately setting the ReativeSource did not work :(

Comment: @Björn Ah! The source should have been the ViewModel and not the Grid. Now it works. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Great! Maybe you should write an answer and mark it as "Accepted" to close this issue.

Comment: You did hep me..write an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Bind your property into DataGrid ItemCollection Class.

xaml....

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnable}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

<DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="0"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
                      BorderBrush="#FF898C95" ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}" CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFDEDBDB"
                      VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFDEDBDB" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      Margin="0,-5,0,0" Background="White" RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Binding="{Binding City}"/>                
            </DataGrid.Columns>            
        </DataGrid>
```

Code...

```
  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                GridData.Add(new UserData { Name = "NAME " + i, City = "CITY " + i });
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<UserData> _gridData=new ObservableCollection<UserData>();
        public ObservableCollection<UserData> GridData
        {
            get { return _gridData; }
            set { _gridData = value; }
        }
```

class....

```
 public class UserData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

        private bool _isEnable = false;
        public bool IsEnable
        {
            get { return _isEnable; }
            set { _isEnable = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The issue is, I want the same style to be applied to 3 different grids if the property changes. And moreover the ItemSource for the grids are generic lists.

Comment: by this way i can select the disabled row by keyboard but not by mouse. is any way for disabling selection of some rows in datagrid?